# How to make an included php file a variable

Tags: php

I would like to make a php file i have a part of a variable i'm building.

ie

```
$print = 'something';
$print .=  include('register_form.php');

print $print;
```

However this doesn't work. register_form.php will be not be included in the $print var, and will be echo'd out before the start of the print out.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I know I could go into register_form.php and make it all a function like register_form() and return its output, however, due to the way I've structured this (and i'm a bit of a newb) this would create more headaches then if I could merely do the above attempt.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this instead through [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

```
ob_start();
include('register_form.php');
$print = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


echo $print;
```

Comment: with this method, would I remove the need for putting everything i'm printing out in a $print variable?

Comment: yes, output buffering will collect all echo/printed stuff into a buffer, and you can fetch its contents with `ob_get_contents()`, and clear it out (plus stop output buffering) with `ob_end_clean()`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is file_get_contents($filename);

Reads the entire file into a string.

[file_get_contents](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

--EDIT

Sorry, just read your question a bit more properly. Output buffing is about the only way to go if you have echo statements in your php form.

A cleaner way would be to have the output form functions return the HTML so you can choose when it's outputted. It maybe a small headache but will like a lot easier in the future.

Comment: Nice! this is more what i was looking for - but on trying it, it echos out the PHP code as html.

Comment: yes, i'm doing $print .= file_get_contents($filename) and it prints out everything... php and html

Answer (score 0):

Output buffering:

```
ob_start();
include('register_form.php');
$output = ob_get_clean();

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Included files can have return values. By combining this with output buffering you can achieve exactly what you want.

register_form.php

```
ob_start();
// content
return ob_get_clean();
```

Then your code will work:

```
$print = 'something';
$print .=  include 'register_form.php' ;
echo $print;
```